# Flutter set height automatically for TabBarView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My problem is i have to set fixed height for `TabBarView` to solve `RenderBox` error, unfortunately this size is fixed and it couldn't expanded by child heigh. how can i resolve that?

i tested `Expanded`, `SizedBox.expanded` but it doesn't any change

```
Scaffold <----------------parent
    SingleChildScrollView <---child
        Stack   <-----------------child
            Padding <-----------------child
                Column  <-----------------child

                      Container( <--------------child
                      height: 250.0,
                      child: TabBarView(
                        children: [
                          Column(
                          ),
                          Column(
                          ),
                          Column(
                          ),
                        ],
                        controller: tabController,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want your UI to look like, but you can try these 2 solutions:

1. Use `LimitedBox` and give some `maxHeight`

   ```
   SingleChildScrollView(
     physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
     child: Stack(
       children: <Widget>[
         Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             LimitedBox( // use this 
               maxHeight: 200, // give some maxHeight
               child: TabBarView(
                 children: [
                   FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.orange, size: 100,),
                   FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.red, size: 100),
                 ],
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 50),
             FlutterLogo(size: 100),
             SizedBox(height: 100),
             FlutterLogo(size: 100),
           ],
         ),
       ],
     ),
   )
   ```
2. Remove `SingleChildScrollView` and add `Expanded`

   ```
    Stack( // remove SingleChildScrollView
     children: <Widget>[
       Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           Expanded( // use Expanded
             child: TabBarView(
               children: [
                 FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.orange),
                 FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.red),
               ],
             ),
           ),
           SizedBox(height: 50),
           FlutterLogo(size: 100),
           SizedBox(height: 100),
           FlutterLogo(size: 100),
         ],
       ),
     ],
   )
   ```